# TextView below Image not showing up in Android

Tags: android

I am trying to put a text below an image but they are not showing up in android layout.

Here is the screenshot:

[image]

I dont' see any text below image.

And my code: inside a relative layout

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/layout_footer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@color/panelcolor" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/searchicon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingRight="60dp"
        android:src="@drawable/search_white" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/searchText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingRight="60dp"
        android:textColor="@color/whitetext"
        android:layout_below="@+id/searchicon"
        android:text="Search" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/homeicon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingRight="60dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/searchicon"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_home" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/hometext"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingRight="60dp"
        android:textColor="@color/whitetext"
        android:layout_below="@+id/homeicon"
        android:text="Home" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/wishicon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/homeicon"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_favorite" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/wishtext"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingRight="60dp"
        android:textColor="@color/whitetext"
        android:layout_below="@+id/wishicon"
        android:text="Wish List" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/viewicon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingLeft="60dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/wishicon"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_eye" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/viewtext"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingRight="60dp"
        android:textColor="@color/whitetext"
        android:layout_below="@+id/wishicon"
        android:text="Viewed" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Not sure what is wrong?

Comment: show the complete layout xml

Comment: I am not able to add the layout XML

Comment: @AlbAtNf: Added everything.. let me know!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you have put `android:layout_height="match_parent"` for image views and `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` for text views. Either use `wrap_content` for image view or use use a LinearLayout with `android:weight` property. Using LinearLayout would also solve your problem of alignment if it occurs!

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you follow  [Googles Design guidelines](https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/tabs.html#tabs-specs)

(Tabs with icons and text Height - 72dp;
Icon - 24 x 24dp)

Change '`match_parent`' to '`wrap_content`' for the ImageViews

Comment: and if the content is bigger or same size as parent? then wrap_content will have no or negative effect.

Comment: @AlbAtNf As we don't know if there are any specifications for the layout and the basic problem was the layout_height mode i answered according to what was asked

Comment: Sure, but we should make at least clear, under which conditions your solution will work. And this will only work, if the given image source is smaller than the parent.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` instead of `android:layout_below="@+id/homeicon"`.

This aligns the text at the bottom of the parent. You might also need to set `android:layout_alignLeft=""` and align it to the corresponding imageView.

This method will only work, if there is enough padding below the image. This is because the text will now overlap the image.

**EDIT**:
Another way would be, to set the relative layout to a fixed height you know (like 60dp) and set the imageView to a fixed height (like 40dp). Then the TextView will also show up below the ImageView.

Comment: hmm.. what would be the best way?

Comment: If it is consistent, not a hack and if it works, then it is at least a good solution. Don't think, there is something like the best in this case.